# Can't fix the error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domxpath

I am trying to display XML with all the content but I keep getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\bollywood\rss1.php on line 43

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

XML Code:

```
  <channel><title>Entertainment News</title>
  <link>http://www.yournewssite.com</link>
   <description>All the latest news and gossip</description>
   <item>
   <title>title!!</title>
  <link>http://www.yournewssite.com</link>
  <description><![CDATA[<img src=http://yourwebsite.com/i.php?k=d88d4e2b336966b538983783230051c width=100 height=100>
  <BR>Backstreet Boys, *NSYNC, 98 Degrees and O-Town boy band members have collaborated on a song to promote their new movie. <BR>]]>
  </description>
  <ContentItem Href="http://yourwebiste.com/i.php?k=d88d4e2b336966b538983783230051c7">
  <MediaType FormalName="Picture" />
  <MimeType FormalName="image/jpg" />
  <Property FormalName="caption" value="Nick Carter" />
  </ContentItem>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
 <?php

 $q=$_GET["q"];


 if($q=="Google") {
 $xml=("google.xml");
 } elseif($q=="b") {
 $xml=("sample.xml");
 }

 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load($xml);



//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
. "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);
$nodeLists = $xpath->query('ContentItem[@Href=""]');

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i< $x->length; $i++) {

    $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
 $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $item_desc=html_entity_decode($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $item_ContentItem=$xpath->$nodeLists->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   echo ("<p><a href=''" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc);
  echo ("<br>");
  echo var_dump($item_ContentItem);
  }


  ?>
```

This is LINE 43, where I keep getting error:

```
$item_ContentItem=$xpath->$nodeLists->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Change `$item_ContentItem=$xpath->$nodeLists-> ...` to `$item_ContentItem=$nodeLists-> ...`

Comment: Thank you! Now, i am getting this error: 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\bollywood\rss1.php on line 43

Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\bollywood\rss1.php on line 43

Comment: What do you want in `$item_ContentItem` ?

Comment: I think, it's a boolen, that's why it's not working. But I don't know how to set it to boolen. But I am trying to get the href link from ContentItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this XML:

```
<ContentItem Href="http://yourwebiste.com/i.php?k=d88d4e2b336966b538983783230051c7">
    <MediaType FormalName="Picture" />
    <MimeType FormalName="image/jpg" />
    <Property FormalName="caption" value="Nick Carter" />
</ContentItem>
```

This XPath pattern:

```
ContentItem[@Href=""]
```

search for a `<ContentItem>` node at first root level (same level of `<title>`, if the root node is `<channel>`) with an empty `Href` attribute: your desired node is not at first root level and doesn't have an empty `Href` attribute, so your query fails.

To search for `<ContentItem>` in any tree position with `Href` attribute you have to use this pattern:

```
//ContentItem[@Href]
```

(`//` means: “search in any position”)

Then, `<ContentItem>` has not a node value, and its childnodes are two `<MediaType>` nodes and one `<Property>` node (both without node values). Your

```
$nodeLists->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

select `<MediaType FormalName="Picture" />` and try to extract its node value, an empty string.

To retrieve the `Href` attributes, use this syntax:

```
$nodeLists = $xpath->query( '//ContentItem[@Href]' );
$item_ContentItem = $nodeLists->item(0)->getAttribute( 'Href' );
```

Or — if you want directly select attribute with XPath:

```
$item_ContentItem = $xpath->query( '//ContentItem[@Href]/@Href' )->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO much!! You are a life saver! It's done and workking perfectly. Thank you!!